# Use a symfony route with parameters in a click event for highchart series

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, highcharts

I'm using the [ObHighchartsBundle](https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle) to make charts in my Symfony project.

I now successfully have a chart on a dashboard with series that has (the same) links to the given data;

[image]

What I want to accomplish is to make each data series (order status) a link to the list of orders with a filter applied so that you only see the results per location and the clicked status.

For example; if I click on the planned orders of location 1 (blue far right), I want to open the list of orders where only the planned orders of location 1 are shown.

This is my code to sort the data correct for this output;

```
$data = $em->getRepository(Order::class)
    ->getOrdersByStatusAndLocation();

$orderStatuses = [];
$locations = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!in_array($row['name'], $locations)) {
        $locations[] = $row['name'];
    }

    $orderStatuses[$row['status']][$row['name']] = $row['number_of_orders'];
}

$result = [];
foreach ($orderStatuses as $status => $value) {
    $row = [
        'name' => $status,
        'data' => array_fill(0, count($locations), 0)
    ];

    foreach ($value as $location => $numOfOrders) {
        $row['data'][array_search($location, $locations)] = $numOfOrders;
    }

    $result[] = $row;
}
```

And the my `$result`s var_dump() like this;

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'planned' (length=7)
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 2
          1 => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'completed' (length=9)
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 6
          1 => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'denied' (length=6)
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 9
          1 => int 0
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'terminated' (length=10)
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 4
          1 => int 0
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'created' (length=7)
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 0
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'canceled' (length=8)
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 4
          1 => int 0
```

with my `$locations` looking like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Location 1' (length=10)
  1 => string 'Location 2' (length=10)
```

For my click event on each serie I have created this url;

```
$orderListAbsoluteUrl = $this->generateUrl(
    'porder_index',
    [],
    UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
);

$onClickFunc = new Expr("function () {
    location.href = '". $orderListAbsoluteUrl ."'
}");
```

I'm using this `$result`s and `$onClickFunc` variables inside my chart object like this;

```
$plotOptions = [
    'stacking' => 'normal',
    'cursor' => 'pointer',
    'point' => [
        'events' => [
            'click' => $onClickFunc
        ]
    ]
];

$ob = new Highchart();
$ob->chart->renderTo('barchart');  // The #id of the div where to render the chart
$ob->chart->type('bar');
$ob->plotOptions->series($plotOptions);
$ob->title->text('Orders per Location');
$ob->credits->enabled(false); // remove highcharts.com credits link
$ob->xAxis->title(['text'  => 'Locations']);
$ob->xAxis->categories($locations);
$ob->yAxis->title(['text'  => 'Orders']);
$ob->yAxis->allowDecimals(false);
$ob->series($result);
```

The only thing that remains is to add the filter inside my link.

Now, I'm making use of [Sonata](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/) for the back-end, so filters are already available. So I think I just need to modify my `$result`s a bit to add the values for the filter and then just add that part of the array in my `$orderListAbsoluteUrl` as a second parameter, but I can't figure how my `$result`s should look.

I have an idea according to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3pxosb4x/), if you look from line 46 of the JavaScript part.

I know my filters parameter for my URL should look like this;

```
$filters = [
    'status' => ['type' => null, 'value' => 'XXXXXX'],
    'location' => ['type' => null, 'value' => 'YYYYYY'],
];
```

So that my URL become something like this:

```
$orderListAbsoluteUrl = $this->generateUrl(
    'porder_index',
    ['filter' => $filters],
    UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
);
```

I hope my question is clear enough and that there is somebody out there who could help me with my situation. I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a hash as a data point rather than just a single number so you could set the URL in that and use it later in the click event.

First create the URL for each filter when creating the results array.

```
$orderStatuses[$row['status']][$row['name']] = [
    // "y" as the axis point for HighCharts to use
    'y'     => $row['number_of_orders'],
    'url'   => $urlGenerator->generate(
        'porder_index',
        [
            'filters' => [
                'status' => ['type' => null, 'value' => $row['status']],
                'location' => ['type' => null, 'value' => $row['name']],
            ]
        ],
        UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
    )
;
```

This should end up with you getting an array similar to the following..

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'planned' (length=7)
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 =>
            array (size=2)
              'y' => int 2
              'url' => string 'https://....?filters..' (length=X)
          1 =>
            array (size=2)
              'y' => int 0
              'url' => string 'https://....?filters..' (length=X)
  //...
```

Then in your `plotOptions.series.point.events.click` method you can just use that url as it is now an attribute of the point/this that is passed to the function.

```
$plotOptions = [
    'stacking' => 'normal',
    'cursor' => 'pointer',
    'point' => [
        'events' => [
            'click' => new Expr("function () {
                location.href = this.url;
            }")
        ]
    ]
];
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95ncsm9e/) with an edited version of one of the HighChart demos with the series data changed a little. It alerts the `url` property when you click but you can do whatever with it at that point.

A benefit of doing it this way rather than trying to create the url on the frontend is that you don't have to make sure the frontend and backend are synced up when you make any route changes, you just have to make sure Symfony is producing the right data.

**NOTE** There might be an issue if ObHighCharts doesn't convert the data point arrays to objects but I can't be sure.